# Why does the build fail trying to find boost.hpp?

Tags: ios, iotivity

I am trying to build IoTivity for iOS and following the instructions [here](https://wiki.iotivity.org/ios_build_instructions) but I keep getting this error which terminates the build.

```
service/resource-encapsulation/include/RCSException.h:33:10: fatal error: 'boost/config.hpp' 
file not found
#include <boost/config.hpp>
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
scons: *** [out/ios/arm64/debug/service/resource-encapsulation/src/common/expiryTimer/src/ExpiryTimerImpl.o] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

When I look in my boost framework, I do see the config.hpp file.  Does anyone have any ideas why it would be unable to find the file.

Comment: Have you set up "Framework Search Paths" in your target's build settings?

Comment: @PhillipMills It is being built as a part of a larger process using SConscript files.  I am not familiar with them and trying to figure them out.  Do you know how I would check that>

Comment: If you are just starting with IoTivity I would strongly encourage using iotivity-lite over iotivity.  OFC stopped development on iotivity a little over a year ago and has only done mantance updates. All development efforts have gone into iotivity-lite. At this point in time the original iotivity can only be certified for version 1.3 of the iotivity specification. while iotivity-lite can be certified for version 2.x.